How do I derive the result using this substitution?
I'm really struggling on how to derive the result for this:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}\,dx$$
Now I read on this website: https://zackyzz.github.io/feynman.html#chapter5
That you can substitute $x \to x^3$
And you end up with this result:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{3\ln(x^3+1)}{x}\,dx$$
Now, I tried doing the U-substitution $u = x^3$, and in the end I ended up with:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}{3x}\,dx$$
The results look really similar, and I checked with Wolfram Alpha and they are the same, but I'm not sure how to go from here to the website's result where it's $3ln(x^3+1)$
I plotted the 2 functions by themselves without the integral sign, and they look really different, but I guess the area under them is the same.
**How can I go from this
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}\,dx$$
to
$$\int_0^1\frac{3\ln(x^3+1)}{x}\,dx$$
Thank you.

Do you know Dilogarithms? If yes, the indefinite integral is $-\text{Li}_2(-x)+C$

I see I see. I guess I was more trying to show that the result of the dilogarithm evaluated at -1 is pi squared / 12, but thank you regardless!

First, do note that the integral you are trying to do is improper.  (Although the integrand is not defined at $x=0$, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}$ exists, so this does not cause a problem; in my head I had done the limit for $\ln(x)/x$ for some reason...)
Second, $x\to x^3$ is not a $u$-substitution setting $u=x^3$; it is the inverse of that: you substitute $x$ with $x^3$, which means as a $u$-substitution it would be $u=\sqrt[3]{x}$.
So starting from $\int\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}\,dx$, setting $u=\sqrt[3]{x}$, we have $x=u^3$; so $dx = 3u^2du$. Thus,
$$\int\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}\,dx = \int\frac{\ln(u^3+1)}{u^3}(3u^2)\,du = \int\frac{3\ln(u^3+1)}{u}\,du.$$

Thank you, sir! May I ask, could you please clarify what does x->x^3 really mean? I'm very confused, how could we set x to be itself cubed ?

@james_math_learner I said what it means: it means "replace $x$ with $x^3$." So wherever you see $x$ you put $x^3$.

Wait never mind! I think I understand now. So you basically say that some x is some u^3, instead of the other way around

Thank you, Arturo. Your support really helped me!

The integral is a proper one as $0$ is not a singular point. By the way I do not understand the reason for a downvote (+)

@RyszardSzwarc The integrand is not defined at $0$; you could extend it continuously, but as written I would call it an improper integral.

But then the integral of ${x^2\over x}$ on $(0,1]$ is improper. I would call $0$ an apparent singular point of the integrand.

@RyszardSzwarc You are right, and in my head I was thinking $\ln(x)/x$ and getting an infinite limit. I'll fix it.
